# My BizTalk orchestration is not consistent

Tags: biztalk

I have BizTalk orchestration where it reads xml file calls .net class from expression shape and send file to send location but it doesn't work always. It only works like 3 out of 5 times. When it doesn't process my orchestration, I am getting "Could not load file or assembly 'XXXX, Version=1.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." 
Please help.  Thank you.

Comment: Does the error actually say xxxxx xxxxxx?

Comment: Am I correct that the assembly that is cannot read is your the one which contains your .net class? Is your environment only a single BizTalk server?

Comment: Does your environment have multiple Servers/Host Instances?  If so, the DLLs may not be deployed on all servers.

Answer (score 1):

On each BizTalk server with a BizTalk host instance, you need to verify that the assembly is in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). If you can load a Visual Studio or Windows SDK command prompt on each, then run `gacutil /l > c:/gac.txt` and it will output everything in the GAC to a text file called gac.txt on your C: drive. Look in that file to verify that the assembly (and the right version of that assembly) is deployed on EACH BizTalk server that could be running a BizTalk host instance.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make changes to an application, and deploy those changes, I find it helpful to restart the host instance your application is running on.

Also, if you are using an external assembly, perhaps in an orchestration or a map, you need to make sure that assembly is in the GAC (global assembly cache).